# Pandas align the Name and IP into two diffrent column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Unix DNS name and IP address in the below format, i want them to be aligned into two different columns in order to segregate DNS Server names in first columns and IP's in second column.

**Below is raw data Sample:**

```
 dns1-example
        forwarders { 192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.141; };

 dns2-exampe
        forwarders { 192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.141; };
```

**Desired Output:**

```
  DNS_NAME                  Forwarders_IP
 dns1-example               192.168.11.250 192.168.11.140 192.168.11.141
 dns2-example               192.168.11.250 192.168.11.140 192.168.11.141
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format is very uncommon, so possible solution is use `read_csv` with splitting by `{` and then post processing - first convert values with `forwarders` in first column to missing values and forward filling them, in second column are removed unnecessary values by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with remove rows with missing values in second column by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""
dns1-example
        forwarders { 192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.141; };

 dns2-exampe
        forwarders { 192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.141; };"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="{", names=['DNS_NAME','Forwarders_IP'])

print (df)
              DNS_NAME                                      Forwarders_IP
0         dns1-example                                                NaN
1          forwarders    192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.14...
2          dns2-exampe                                                NaN
3          forwarders    192.168.11.250; 192.168.11.140; 192.168.11.14...

m = df['DNS_NAME'].str.contains('forwarders', na=False)
df['DNS_NAME'] = df['DNS_NAME'].mask(m).ffill().str.strip()
df['Forwarders_IP'] = df['Forwarders_IP'].str.strip(' };').str.replace(';','')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Forwarders_IP']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       DNS_NAME                                 Forwarders_IP
0  dns1-example  192.168.11.250 192.168.11.140 192.168.11.141
1   dns2-exampe  192.168.11.250 192.168.11.140 192.168.11.141
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, looks great +1, in case we need to read the file `dns_file.txt then , how can we use this.

Comment: @user294110 - change `df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="{", names=['DNS_NAME','Forwarders_IP'])` to `df = pd.read_csv('dns_file.txt', sep="{", names=['DNS_NAME','Forwarders_IP'])`